# How to pull a number posts from a specific Taxonomy within a Custom Post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

Wondering if anyone can help.

I'm putting together a site which features music reviews, amongst other things. The set up is built on a custom post type and a number of associated taxonomies.

**Post type:**

- my_albumreviews

**Taxonomies:**

- artist
- label
- release date

On a page displaying an album review ( `my_albumreviews` post type ), under the main content I need a section which shows **"Other reviews from this artist"**. I think I'm along the right lines with this but just can't get it to work.

```
$artistname = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'artist');
        $args = array(
        'post_type'=>'my_albumreviews',
        'tax_query'=>array(array('taxonomy'=>'artist',
                    'field'=>'id',
                    'terms'=> '$artistname'
                    ))
        );
$artist_reviews = new WP_query($args);
```

This is then followed by..

```
while ($artist_reviews->have_posts()) : $artist_reviews->the_post();
```

..which returns nothing to the page.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What comes after `while ($artist_reviews->have_posts()) : $artist_reviews->the_post();`?

Comment: I'll be running standard in-loop functions like `the_title()` to display key info from all other reviews by the current artist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@Frederik**, **@Bainternet** & **Otto**

Thanks for your help, guys. A thousand thanks for your help! The key lied in stripping the taxonomy's slug out of `wp_get_post_terms()`.

Here's my final, fully functioning code:

```
$artist_taxo = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'artist' );  //Fetch terms from taxonomy 'artist'
$artistname = $artistslug[0]->slug;  //Pull slug from $artist_taxo into $artistname

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'cdx_albumreviews',  //Specify custom post name
    'numberposts' => -1,  //Return all posts
    'artist' => $artistname //Taxo 'artist' is equal to $artistname
    );

    $artist_reviews = new wp_query($args);
    while ($artist_reviews->have_posts()) : $artist_reviews->the_post();
    the_title();
    endwhile;
```

A massive thanks.

Mathew

Answer (score 0):

The `get_the_terms()` returns a list of term objects. So first of all, you need to treat the output as a list rather than a single element. The name you're looking for is stored in the `name` field.

```
$artistnames = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'artist');
if (!empty($artistnames)) : ?>
    foreach ($artistnames as $obj) {
         $name = $obj->name;
         // Do something with the name
    }
```

Maybe you should use a custom field instead of a taxonomy? My experience is that they work better for singletons.

You get the custom fields in the loop by [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta):

```
<?php $meta_values = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'artist', true); ?>
```

Hopefully this helps you somewhat!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Frederik. Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be working. I've substituted `$artistname` for the newly stored `$name` in my tax query but it's still not pushing anything to the page when I call for `the_title()`. I'll only ever be pulling one result into $artistname -- does this help matters? And I'm keen to stay on Taxonomies as their storage will help reduce errors through spelling eg. Beatles / Beetles. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

When using `'tax_query'` with `'field'=>'id'` then terms should be an array of term ids, so instead of using get_the_terms() use wp_get_object_terms() and set the fields to ids that way you will get an array with term ids so:

```
$args = array('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'fields' => 'ids');
$artistnames = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'artist',$args);
```

and you should be set using your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$artists = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'artist');
foreach ($artists as $artist) $artids[] = $artist->term_id;
$args = array(
   'post_type'=>'my_albumreviews',
   'tax_query'=>array(
      array('taxonomy'=>'artist',
         'field'=>'id',
         'terms'=> $artids,
      )
   )
);
$artist_reviews = new WP_query($args);
```

get_the_terms returns an array of objects. So you have to loop through it and save the ID numbers into another array to pass to the tax_query.

Also '$artistname' is the string '$artistname'. If it's a variable, it shouldn't have single quotes around it.